# Ubuntu 14.04 not lauching after login

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, nvidia, login

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04. First, when I launched the CD, I wanted to try Ubuntu without installing it, but it didn't work.

I don't know why it was stuck in the screen of the selection where you choose if you want to install or try Ubuntu. So I chose to install Ubuntu, and it worked well until the installation was finished. When it asked me to reboot the computer, I did and again it was stuck and didn't reboot.

I shut it down and tried to lauch Ubuntu. In the grub menu I chose Ubuntu, and it brings me to the login screen where I try to login, but it was again stuck when logging on.

I tried multiple times, I also tried the guest session but that didn't work either. And sometimes my mouse doesn't show, it looked like it was stuck even before login.

I am in dual-boot boot with windows 10, using hybrid graphics Intel + Nvidia GTX 880M.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Press Ctrl+Alt+F1 when you get a login prompt, login into console and run there the command `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'`. Then [edit] your question and post there the output, or give a link to a screenshot.

Comment: Hi, here is what I get when I enter lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D' in the console : http://prntscr.com/858tia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install video drivers. Connect to internet by cable and run in console

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo reboot
```

Be very careful with the commands.

Comment: I fixed a typo. It is `nvidia-352`

Comment: Thanks! But I already did with 346 and it worked. How can I do to upgrade it?

Comment: Maybe you do not need to, if it works with 346. But you have GTX-880, that is very new. You can run `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` and run the commands from the answer. Then reboot. If you can boot to GUI, you do not have to go to console for that. Start terminal by Ctrl+Alt+T. You will be able to copy and paste.

Comment: Thanks! but now when I launch Ubuntu there is a black screen with "APCI PCC Probe failed". Bur after It works perfectly. Does it matter?

Comment: Do not worry, if it works OK.

Comment: "Be very careful with the commands." is nice =)

Comment: @A.B. The point is that in this case they cannot be copied.